# Kivy how to access widget in function, no KV just python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Sorry for my very basic problem but I have been searching around of an answer for an hour to no avail.

this is my basic code:

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(LoginScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    l = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    sound_btn = Button(text="Play Sound", font_size = 300)
    word_bx = TextInput(multiline=False,hint_text='type here...',font_size=300)
    submit_btn = Button(text = 'Submit', font_size=300)
    submit_btn.bind(on_press = self.submitAction)
    l.add_widget(sound_btn)
    l.add_widget(word_bx)
    l.add_widget(submit_btn)
    self.add_widget(l)

def submitAction(self,*args):
    if self.word_bx.text == KivyApp.word:
        KivyApp.point+=1
    self.word_bx.text=""
    KivyApp.i +=1
    print(KivyApp.point)
```

As you can see, in the submitAction function I want to reference the word_bx widget, but this throws an error stating that Class LoginPage has no attribute word_bx. I then tried to place 'ids' infront of self but that throws another error. What am I doing wrong? sorry for my incompetence..

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
word_bx = TextInput(multiline=False,hint_text='type here...',font_size=300)
...
l.add_widget(word_bx)
```

define `word_bx` as a temporary variable. It's not available after `__init__()` exits. If you want it to be persistent so that you can access it from other methods, you need to make it a member of the class.

```
self.word_bx = TextInput(multiline=False,hint_text='type here...',font_size=300)
...
l.add_widget(self.word_bx)
```

Then the line

```
self.word_bx.text=""
```

in `submitAction()` will refer to something that actually exists.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, this is not the solution. I have to add the textbox to the layout widget, I cannot just declare it as self kivy doesn't like that.

Comment: You reported your error as Class LoginPage has no attribute word_bx. I explained the cause of that. I don't understand "I cannot just declare it as self kivy doesn't like that." Kivy can't tell whether your variable is declared as `self.word_bx` or `word_bx`. Can you be a bit more explicit about what Kivy doesn't like? After you have made the AttributeError go away, what other error do you get?

Comment: Yes, but if I did 'self.word_bx' i get an error saying that the class has no attribute word_bx. I think its my fault, because I did not show you the entire code, I do not build this Class it is part of a screen manager otherwise I think your solution would have worked.

Comment: You have to do `self.word_bx` in *both* methods. Do you get an error if you do this in `__init__`? I think you won't. `self.word_bx = TextInput(multiline=False,hint_text='type here...',font_size=300)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using Lambda and making the function external to the class:

```
def submitAction(text):
    if text == KivyApp.word:
        KivyApp.point+=1
    KivyApp.i +=1
    print(KivyApp.point)

class LoginScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        l = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        sound_btn = Button(text="Play Sound", font_size = 300)
        word_bx = TextInput(multiline=False,hint_text='type here...',font_size=300)
        submit_btn = Button(text = 'Submit', font_size=300)
        submit_btn.bind(on_press = lambda *a:submitAction(word_bx.text))
        l.add_widget(sound_btn)
        l.add_widget(word_bx)
        l.add_widget(submit_btn)
        self.add_widget(l)
```